# Erro ao adicionar alunos em uma turma 'The given id must not be null!'

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Quando clico em Incluir aluno aparece esse erro mas não entendo porque, alguém pra me dá um luz, obrigada.

**Erro no console**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!    at
> org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:198)
> ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:269)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]    at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[na:1.8.0_231]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> ~[na:1.8.0_231]

**Entidade Aluno**

```
  @Entity
    public class Aluno {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long codigo;
        
        @NotNull(message = "*O campo Nome é de preenchimento obrigatório")
        private String nome;
        
        private String apelido;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="AlunosTurmas", 
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "codigo_turma", "codigo_aluno" }),
            joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_aluno"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_turma")
    )
    private List<Turma> turmas; 
*....Getters and Setters*
```

**Entidade Turma**

```
@Entity
public class Turma {
    
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    
    @NotEmpty(message = "*O campo Nome é de preenchimento obrigatório")
    @NotBlank(message = "*O campo Nome é de preenchimento obrigatório")
    private String nome;
    
    private String hora_inicio;
    
    private String hora_fim;
    
    private int vagas;
    
    private String professor;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="AlunosTurmas", //nome da nova tabela
        uniqueConstraints  = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "codigo_turma", "id_aluno" }), //id curso e turma são únicos 
        joinColumns        = @JoinColumn(name = "codigo_turma" ), //chave estrangeira de turma
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_aluno")       //chave estrangeira de aluno
    )
    private List<Aluno> alunos;
```

**Controler Turmas**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/turmas")
public class TurmaController {

 @PostMapping("/associarAlunoTurma")
        public String associarAluno(@ModelAttribute Aluno aluno, @RequestParam Long codigoTurma) {
           
         Turma turma = turmasRepository.getOne(codigoTurma);
            aluno = alunosRepository.getOne(aluno.getCodigo());  

            turma.getAlunos().add(aluno);
            turmaService.salvarAlunoTurma(turma);

            return "redirect:/turmas/detalhesTurma/" + codigoTurma;
        }

     
        @GetMapping("/detalhesTurma/{codigo}")//aqui passa o próprio cód da turma na requisição 
        public ModelAndView getAlunoDetalhes(@PathVariable(name = "codigo") Long codigo) {

            Turma turma = turmasRepository.getOne(codigo);
            
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/turma/detalhesTurma");
            mv.addObject("turma", turma);
            List <Aluno> alunosNaoAssociados = alunosRepository.findAll();
            alunosNaoAssociados.removeAll(turma.getAlunos());
            mv.addObject("alunos", alunosNaoAssociados);

            return mv;
        }
```

> **destalhesTurma.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{/LayoutPadrao}">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    
<title>Agrestina</title>


</head>
 <body >
<section layout:fragment="content">
        
     <!-- partial -->
  <div class="content-wrapper" style="margin-top: -70px;">
    <div class="page-header">
       <h3 class="page-title"> Cadastro de Turmas </h3>
         <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
           <ol class="breadcrumb">
             <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/turmas">Listar</a></li>
             <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Cadastrar Turma</li>
           </ol>
         </nav>
   </div>
            
     <form class="forms-sample" th:action="@{/turmas/associarAlunoTurma(codigoTurma=${turma.codigo})}" method="post">
      
              <div class="col-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-body"> 
                   <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                            <label for="exampleSelectGender">Selecione o aluno para incluir na turma</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelectGender" th:field="*{alunos}">
                              <option value="" selected="selected">- Selecione -</option>
                              <option th:each="aluno : ${alunos}" th:value="${aluno.codigo}" 
                                      th:text="${aluno.nome}">Female</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<!--                        <i class="mdi mdi-content-save btn-icon-prepend"></i>   Incluir  </button>  -->
                    
                    </div>      
                 </div>
                </div>
              </div>
       </form>  
       
       
<!--        TABELA DE ALUNOS DA TURMA  -->
       
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title text-success">Turma: #<span th:utext="${turma.codigo}"></span> <span th:utext="${turma.nome}"></span> </h4>
                   <table class="table table-responsive table-sm">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="text-dark font-weight-bold"> # </th>
                          <th class="text-dark font-weight-bold"> Nome </th>
                          <th class="text-dark font-weight-bold"> Apelido </th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="aluno : ${turma.alunos}">
                            <td th:text="${aluno.codigo}">1</td>
                            <td th:text="${aluno.nome}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${aluno.apelido}"></td>                      
                            <td class="left">  
<!--                                 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Excluir"  -->
<!--                                     th:href="@{turmas/excluirTurma/{codigo}(codigo=${turma.codigo})}"> -->
<!--                                    <i class=" mdi mdi-delete"></i> -->
<!--                                 </a> -->
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
<!--                             <td colspan="36" th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(turma.alunos)}">Nenhum aluno foi encontrado na turma</td> -->
                         </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
               </div>   
       
       </div>
    </section>
    
 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery-3.3.0.min.js}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/jquery.autocomplete.js}"></script>
 </body>       
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse trecho:

```
Turma turma = turmasRepository.getOne(codigoTurma);
aluno = alunosRepository.getOne(aluno.getCodigo());
```

Ou `codigoTurma` ou `aluno.getCodigo()` é nulo (`null`).

Evite passar `id` nulo, pois causa o erro citado.

Não dou mais detalhes porque não manjo de JPA.